# auto zip download from url

Tags: php, mysql, zip

I need help with one snippet of code that has me ready to explode, involving an automatically downloaded zip folder for an external URL, containing just a single txt file, that I will upload to a mysql database, to complete a project I've been working on for five years.

The short version is I need to get the daily text file from this url:

http://batstrading.com/market_data/shortsales/2014/06/BYXXshvol20140620.txt.zip-dl?mkt=byx

I have tried everything, in a hundred combinations. On those occasions no errors occurred, there were no txt files created nor uploaded to the db , permissions set to 777

zip_open, zip_read, zip_entry_open, zip_entry_read, fgets, fopens, file_get_contents

The long version with a valid url is:

```
function getBATStxtfile($BATSzipurlFile, $BATSZoutputFile)
{  
    $BATSzipurl="http://batstrading.com/market_data/shortsales/2014/06/BYXXshvol20140620.txt.zip-dl?mkt=byx";  

    file_get_contents($BATSzipurl); 

    $batstxtzipFile=zip_open($BATSzipurl);  
    $batstxtzipFile=zip_read($BATSzipurl);  
    $batstxtFile = zip_entry_open($batstxtzipFile;  
    $batstxt = zip_entry_read($batstxtFile);  
    $batstxt = str_replace("Date|Symbol|Short Volume|Total Volume|Market Center", "",$batstxt);  
    $batstxt = str_replace("|",  ",", $batstxt);  
    $batstxt = trim($batstxt);  

    file_put_contents($BATSZoutputFile, $batstxt);

    zip_entry_close($batstxtFile);  
    zip_close($BATSzipurl);  
}
```

I have 3000000 lines of code, 10,000 failed scripts, and all I need to have my life back...is this .txt file retrieved.   Thank you in advance.

Comment: What about error checking? _file_get_contents()_ returns `false` on failure, but you throw away the result, even on success. What do you expect?

Answer (score 0):

Here you go

```
<?php

// fetch zip file
$zip = file_get_contents('http://batstrading.com/market_data/shortsales/2014/06/BYXXshvol20140620.txt.zip-dl?mkt=byx');
file_put_contents('bats.zip', $zip);

// read specific file from zip archive
$txt = file_get_contents('zip://bats.zip#BYXXshvol20140620.txt');

// do text transformations
$txt = str_replace('Date|Symbol|Short Volume|Total Volume|Market Center', '', $txt);
$txt = str_replace('|',  ',', $txt);
$txt = trim($txt);

// output the modified txt to file
file_put_contents('out.txt', $txt);
```